# 3 jqUI tabs one form for each tab getting the action of one of the first 2

Tags: forms, jquery-ui, action, jquery-ui-tabs

I am having the hardest time getting the action of one of the three forms so that I can call the right controller action.  How can you manage to do that?

Is there a way to get the right form, so I can serialize the right data and send it my controller?
I figured out how to get the right action

```
'@Url.Action("SearchByDemographic", "SearchPatients")'
```

I can't figure out how to serialize the form...
This won't work...

```
$('#searchByDemographics').serialize()
```

This is in an ajax call...

```
$('#searchByDemographics').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var urlVal = this.action;// $('#searchByDemographics').attr('action');
        var type = this.method; //$('#searchByDemographics').attr('method');
        debugger;
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SearchByDemographic", "SearchPatients")', //"SearchPatients/SearchByDemographic",
            type: "POST", //this.method,
            data: $('#searchByDemographics').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                $('#list').html(data);
                bindData(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

How can you get the form to searilize it and return it to the controller.

**UPDATE:**
I recently thought of instead of submitting a strongly type model, I would just try the usual form submit methodology.  No dice.  I am still getting 0 form data...  I am at a loss here.  Any body here have anyexperience with Jquery UI Tabs and having a form on each Tab that returns JSON data back to the same tab, or to another tab that is immediately opened?

**UPDATE: INNER-HTML**

```
<DIV class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" sizset="0" jQuery17203071998293053285="41" sizcache05855682300806401="4"><SPAN id=ui-dialog-title-1 class=ui-dialog-title jQuery17203071998293053285="42">&nbsp;</SPAN><A class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role=button href="http://localhost:19283/Encounters/ShowAllEncounters?popId=2#" jQuery17203071998293053285="40"><SPAN class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" jQuery17203071998293053285="43">close</SPAN></A></DIV>
<DIV style="MIN-HEIGHT: 304px; WIDTH: auto; DISPLAY: block; HEIGHT: auto" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" jQuery17203071998293053285="38" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
<DIV>
<DIV id=searchPatient class="float-left ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" jQuery17203071998293053285="52">
<P></P>
<P></P>
<P></P>
<UL class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
<LI class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" jQuery17203071998293053285="56"><A href="#searchByMRN" jQuery17203071998293053285="58">Search By MRN</A></LI>
<LI class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active" jQuery17203071998293053285="57"><A href="#searchByDemographics" jQuery17203071998293053285="59">Search By Demo</A></LI></UL>
<DIV style="MARGIN-TOP: 6px; DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left; MARGIN-LEFT: 6px; MARGIN-RIGHT: 6px" id=searchByMRN class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
<FORM id=formSearchByMRN method=post action=/SearchPatients/SearchByMRN?Length=13 data-ajax-update="#retTable" data-ajax-success="switchToResultTab" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax="true">
<P>
<UL>
<LI><LABEL for=MRN>MRN#</LABEL><BR><INPUT id=MRN name=MRN></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=MRNDrop>MRNDrop</LABEL><BR><SELECT id=MRNDrop name=MRNDrop><OPTION selected value=MPACMRN>Medipac</OPTION> <OPTION value=NWMRN>NorthWest</OPTION> <OPTION value=BEDFORD>Epic</OPTION> <OPTION value=CHILDRENS>Bedford</OPTION> <OPTION value=CHILDRENS>Childrens</OPTION> <OPTION value=MAGEE>Magee</OPTION> <OPTION value=PASSAVANT>Passavant</OPTION> <OPTION value=MERCY>Mercy</OPTION> <OPTION value=BEST>Medicare</OPTION> <OPTION value=HEALTHPLAN>4L Health Plan</OPTION> <OPTION value=EMPIID>EMPI</OPTION></SELECT></LI></UL>
<P></P><INPUT id=submitMRN value="Search by MRN" type=submit> </FORM></DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 50%; DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left" id=searchByDemographics class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" jQuery17203071998293053285="70">
<FORM id=searchByDemographics class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" method=post action=/SearchPatients/SearchByDemographic>
<UL>
<LI><LABEL for=SSN>SSN</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=SSN name=SSN></LI></UL>
<UL>
<P>Or</P></UL>
<UL>
<LI><LABEL for=FirstName>FirstName</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=FirstName name=FirstName></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=LastName>LastName</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=LastName name=LastName></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=dateOfBirth>dateOfBirth</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=dateOfBirth name=dateOfBirth></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=Address1>Address1</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=Address1 name=Address1></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=Address2>Address2</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=Address2 name=Address2></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=City>City</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=City name=City></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=State>State</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=State name=State></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=Country>Country</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=Country name=Country></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=PostCode>PostCode</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=PostCode name=PostCode></LI></UL><INPUT id=submitDemo class=button value="Search By Demographics" type=submit> </FORM></DIV></DIV>
<DIV class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
<DIV style="WIDTH: 826px" dir=ltr id=gbox_list class="ui-jqgrid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<DIV id=lui_list class="ui-widget-overlay jqgrid-overlay"></DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=load_list class="loading ui-state-default ui-state-active" jQuery17203071998293053285="69">undefined</DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 826px" id=gview_list class=ui-jqgrid-view>
<DIV class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-top ui-helper-clearfix"><A style="RIGHT: 0px" class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close HeaderButton" role=link href="javascript:void(0)" jQuery17203071998293053285="66"><SPAN class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n"></SPAN></A><SPAN class=ui-jqgrid-title>My first grid</SPAN></DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 826px" class="ui-state-default ui-jqgrid-hdiv" loading="false" jQuery17203071998293053285="67">
<DIV class=ui-jqgrid-hbox>
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 429px" class=ui-jqgrid-htable role=grid aria-labelledby=gbox_list border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
<THEAD>
<TR class=ui-jqgrid-labels role=rowheader jQuery17203071998293053285="68">
<TH style="WIDTH: 34px" id=list_Select class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" role=columnheader jQuery17203071998293053285="60"><SPAN style="CURSOR: col-resize" class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<DIV id=jqgh_list_Select class="ui-th-div-ie ui-jqgrid-sortable" sizset="0" sizcache05855682300806401="6">Select<SPAN class=s-ico sizset="0" sizcache05855682300806401="6"><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr" sort="asc"></SPAN><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr" sort="desc"></SPAN></SPAN></DIV></TH>
<TH style="WIDTH: 115px" id=list_First_Name class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" role=columnheader jQuery17203071998293053285="61"><SPAN style="CURSOR: col-resize" class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<DIV id=jqgh_list_First_Name class="ui-th-div-ie ui-jqgrid-sortable">First Name<SPAN style="DISPLAY: none" class=s-ico><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr" sort="asc"></SPAN><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr" sort="desc"></SPAN></SPAN></DIV></TH>
<TH style="WIDTH: 115px" id=list_Last_Name class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" role=columnheader jQuery17203071998293053285="62"><SPAN style="CURSOR: col-resize" class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<DIV id=jqgh_list_Last_Name class="ui-th-div-ie ui-jqgrid-sortable">First Name<SPAN style="DISPLAY: none" class=s-ico><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr" sort="asc"></SPAN><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr" sort="desc"></SPAN></SPAN></DIV></TH>
<TH style="WIDTH: 145px" id=list_MRN class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" role=columnheader jQuery17203071998293053285="63"><SPAN style="CURSOR: col-resize" class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<DIV id=jqgh_list_MRN class="ui-th-div-ie ui-jqgrid-sortable">MRN<SPAN style="DISPLAY: none" class=s-ico><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr" sort="asc"></SPAN><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr" sort="desc"></SPAN></SPAN></DIV></TH></TR></THEAD></TABLE></DIV></DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 826px; HEIGHT: 150px" class=ui-jqgrid-bdiv jQuery17203071998293053285="65">
<DIV style="POSITION: relative; HEIGHT: 0.01%">
<DIV></DIV>
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 429px" id=list class=ui-jqgrid-btable role=grid tabIndex=1 aria-labelledby=gbox_list aria-multiselectable=false border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 jQuery17203071998293053285="64">
<TBODY>
<TR style="HEIGHT: auto" class=jqgfirstrow role=row>
<TD style="WIDTH: 34px; HEIGHT: 0px" role=gridcell></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 115px; HEIGHT: 0px" role=gridcell></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 115px; HEIGHT: 0px" role=gridcell></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 145px; HEIGHT: 0px" role=gridcell></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV id=rs_mlist class=ui-jqgrid-resize-mark>&nbsp;</DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 1000" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" jQuery17203071998293053285="44"></DIV>
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 1000" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" jQuery17203071998293053285="45"></DIV>
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 1000" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" jQuery17203071998293053285="46"></DIV>
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 1000" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" jQuery17203071998293053285="47"></DIV>
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 1000" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se" jQuery17203071998293053285="48"></DIV>
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 1000" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" jQuery17203071998293053285="49"></DIV>
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 1000" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" jQuery17203071998293053285="50"></DIV>
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 1000" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" jQuery17203071998293053285="51"></DIV>
```

As you can see, I technically have two forms on this page, but you think that by identifying which form you are using  ie `$('#formID').submit()` you should be able to mitigate the confusion.  Somehow or the other though, that is not working.

**UPDATE: changed the ID's around and still can't get the thing to work... I did however get this to work using Ajax.BeginForm**

```
<DIV class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" sizset="0" jQuery17205444165684387369="41" sizcache016230309957162758="4"><SPAN id=ui-dialog-title-1 class=ui-dialog-title jQuery17205444165684387369="42">&nbsp;</SPAN><A class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role=button href="http://localhost:19283/Encounters/ShowAllEncounters?popId=2#" jQuery17205444165684387369="40"><SPAN class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" jQuery17205444165684387369="43">close</SPAN></A></DIV>
<DIV style="MIN-HEIGHT: 304px; WIDTH: auto; DISPLAY: block; HEIGHT: auto" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" sizset="1" jQuery17205444165684387369="38" sizcache016230309957162758="8" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
<DIV sizset="1" sizcache016230309957162758="8">
<DIV id=searchPatient class="float-left ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" sizset="1" jQuery17205444165684387369="52" sizcache016230309957162758="8">
<P></P>
<P></P>
<P></P>
<UL class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
<LI class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" jQuery17205444165684387369="55"><A href="#searchByMRN" jQuery17205444165684387369="57">Search By MRN</A></LI>
<LI class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active" jQuery17205444165684387369="56"><A href="#searchByDemographics" jQuery17205444165684387369="58">Search By Demo</A></LI></UL>
<DIV style="MARGIN-TOP: 6px; DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left; MARGIN-LEFT: 6px; MARGIN-RIGHT: 6px" id=searchByMRN class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
<FORM id=formSearchByMRN method=post action=/SearchPatients/SearchByMRN?Length=13 sizset="0" sizcache016230309957162758="8" data-ajax-update="#retTable" data-ajax-success="switchToResultTab" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax="true">
<P>
<UL>
<LI><LABEL for=MRN>MRN#</LABEL><BR><INPUT id=MRN name=MRN></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=MRNDrop>MRNDrop</LABEL><BR><SELECT id=MRNDrop name=MRNDrop><OPTION selected value=MPACMRN>Medipac</OPTION> <OPTION value=NWMRN>NorthWest</OPTION> <OPTION value=BEDFORD>Epic</OPTION> <OPTION value=CHILDRENS>Bedford</OPTION> <OPTION value=CHILDRENS>Childrens</OPTION> <OPTION value=MAGEE>Magee</OPTION> <OPTION value=PASSAVANT>Passavant</OPTION> <OPTION value=MERCY>Mercy</OPTION> <OPTION value=BEST>Medicare</OPTION> <OPTION value=HEALTHPLAN>4L Health Plan</OPTION> <OPTION value=EMPIID>EMPI</OPTION></SELECT></LI></UL>
<P></P><INPUT id=submitMRN value="Search by MRN" type=submit> </FORM></DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 50%; DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left" id=searchByDemographicsDiv sizset="1" sizcache016230309957162758="8">
<FORM id=searchByDemographics class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" method=post action=/SearchPatients/SearchByDemographic sizset="1" jQuery17205444165684387369="69" sizcache016230309957162758="8">
<UL>
<LI><LABEL for=SSN>SSN</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=SSN name=SSN></LI></UL>
<UL>
<P>Or</P></UL>
<UL>
<LI><LABEL for=FirstName>FirstName</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=FirstName name=FirstName></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=LastName>LastName</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=LastName name=LastName></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=dateOfBirth>dateOfBirth</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=dateOfBirth name=dateOfBirth></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=Address1>Address1</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=Address1 name=Address1></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=Address2>Address2</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=Address2 name=Address2></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=City>City</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=City name=City></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=State>State</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=State name=State></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=Country>Country</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=Country name=Country></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=PostCode>PostCode</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=PostCode name=PostCode></LI></UL><INPUT id=submitDemo class=button value="Search By Demographics" type=submit> </FORM></DIV></DIV>
<DIV class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
<DIV style="WIDTH: 826px" dir=ltr id=gbox_list class="ui-jqgrid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<DIV id=lui_list class="ui-widget-overlay jqgrid-overlay"></DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=load_list class="loading ui-state-default ui-state-active" jQuery17205444165684387369="68">undefined</DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 826px" id=gview_list class=ui-jqgrid-view>
<DIV class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-top ui-helper-clearfix"><A style="RIGHT: 0px" class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close HeaderButton" role=link href="javascript:void(0)" jQuery17205444165684387369="65"><SPAN class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n"></SPAN></A><SPAN class=ui-jqgrid-title>My first grid</SPAN></DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 826px" class="ui-state-default ui-jqgrid-hdiv" loading="false" jQuery17205444165684387369="66">
<DIV class=ui-jqgrid-hbox>
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 429px" class=ui-jqgrid-htable role=grid aria-labelledby=gbox_list border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
<THEAD>
<TR class=ui-jqgrid-labels role=rowheader jQuery17205444165684387369="67">
<TH style="WIDTH: 34px" id=list_Select class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" role=columnheader jQuery17205444165684387369="59"><SPAN style="CURSOR: col-resize" class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<DIV id=jqgh_list_Select class="ui-th-div-ie ui-jqgrid-sortable" sizset="0" sizcache016230309957162758="6">Select<SPAN class=s-ico sizset="0" sizcache016230309957162758="6"><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr" sort="asc"></SPAN><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr" sort="desc"></SPAN></SPAN></DIV></TH>
<TH style="WIDTH: 115px" id=list_First_Name class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" role=columnheader jQuery17205444165684387369="60"><SPAN style="CURSOR: col-resize" class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<DIV id=jqgh_list_First_Name class="ui-th-div-ie ui-jqgrid-sortable">First Name<SPAN style="DISPLAY: none" class=s-ico><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr" sort="asc"></SPAN><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr" sort="desc"></SPAN></SPAN></DIV></TH>
<TH style="WIDTH: 115px" id=list_Last_Name class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" role=columnheader jQuery17205444165684387369="61"><SPAN style="CURSOR: col-resize" class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<DIV id=jqgh_list_Last_Name class="ui-th-div-ie ui-jqgrid-sortable">First Name<SPAN style="DISPLAY: none" class=s-ico><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr" sort="asc"></SPAN><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr" sort="desc"></SPAN></SPAN></DIV></TH>
<TH style="WIDTH: 145px" id=list_MRN class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" role=columnheader jQuery17205444165684387369="62"><SPAN style="CURSOR: col-resize" class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr">&nbsp;</SPAN>
<DIV id=jqgh_list_MRN class="ui-th-div-ie ui-jqgrid-sortable">MRN<SPAN style="DISPLAY: none" class=s-ico><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr" sort="asc"></SPAN><SPAN class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr" sort="desc"></SPAN></SPAN></DIV></TH></TR></THEAD></TABLE></DIV></DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 826px; HEIGHT: 150px" class=ui-jqgrid-bdiv jQuery17205444165684387369="64">
<DIV style="POSITION: relative; HEIGHT: 0.01%">
<DIV></DIV>
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 429px" id=list class=ui-jqgrid-btable role=grid tabIndex=1 aria-labelledby=gbox_list aria-multiselectable=false border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 jQuery17205444165684387369="63">
<TBODY>
<TR style="HEIGHT: auto" class=jqgfirstrow role=row>
<TD style="WIDTH: 34px; HEIGHT: 0px" role=gridcell></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 115px; HEIGHT: 0px" role=gridcell></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 115px; HEIGHT: 0px" role=gridcell></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 145px; HEIGHT: 0px" role=gridcell></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV id=rs_mlist class=ui-jqgrid-resize-mark>&nbsp;</DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
```

Here is the `Ajax.BeginForm(...){`

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchByDemographic", "SearchPatients", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", LoadingElementId = Url.Content("~/Images/ajax-loader.gif"), OnSuccess = "binddata", OnFailure = "FailToTab" }, new { id = "searchByDemographics" })){
```

Comment: whistlin' the tune to rocket man...

Comment: What does the `serialize` call produce? What do you mean it's not working?

Comment: literally nothing.  When debugging my controller, I literally have an empty object as the parameter.  When I debug the javascript the following code: var 'urlVal = this.action;' does not return the correct action... The following attempt to serialize the form is also empty...
'var formJson = $("#searchByDemographics").serializeArray();'

Comment: Any chance you can show your generated HTML?

Comment: Try JSON.stringify($('#searchByDemographics')) or JSON.stringify($('#searchByDemographics').serialize()). When you're sending a request with content type set to application/json, it should actually be a json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have some invalid markup that's causing the problem:

```
<DIV style="WIDTH: 50%; DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left" id=searchByDemographics class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" jQuery17203071998293053285="70">
<FORM id=searchByDemographics class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" method=post action=/SearchPatients/SearchByDemographic>
```

and:

```
<DIV style="MARGIN-TOP: 6px; DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left; MARGIN-LEFT: 6px; MARGIN-RIGHT: 6px" id=searchByMRN class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
<FORM id=formSearchByMRN method=post action=/SearchPatients/SearchByMRN?Length=13 data-ajax-update="#retTable" data-ajax-success="switchToResultTab" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax="true">
```

Both of the above (pairs of) elements have the same `id` attribute, which is not allowed. Your selector is most likely grabbing the first element in the DOM it encounters with the `id` you've supplied (the `div`). The `div` does not have `action` or `method` properties, so they end up being undefined.

The `submit` event is still bubbling up to the `div` with that `id` which is why your submit handler is still working.

If you make the `id`s unique, everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try Manual Form Searlization like this,

```
 function formSubMission(){
        var obj = {};
        $('#formId :input').each(function(i, el){
            var name = el.name;
            var val = el.value;
            if(name!=""){
                obj[name] = val;
            }
        });

         $.ajax({
                  url: "test.html",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: obj,
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function(data){
                    alert("Sucess")
                  }, 
                  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                     alert("Error")
                  }
            });
 }
```